# Adding hours to unix time stamp in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to add 5 hours to a certain unix time stamp. Its like start and stop time for a game. So I have the knowledge of start time and the duration of the game. I need to put end time. How this can be done in python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

UNIX timestamps are in second units.

```
end_timestamp = start_timestamp + 5 * 60 * 60
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be explicit and work with the following:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, datetime
>>> a = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
>>> b = a + timedelta(hours=5)
>>> c = time.mktime(b.timetuple())
>>> c
18000.0
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(c)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 6, 0)
```