# Modifying timestamp in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a giveaway command for myself, but I can't figure out how to display the end time of the giveaway as an embed timestamp, could anyone help? I read through the [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.timestamp) docs but that did not really help, maybe I am stupid, but I cant figure it out.

```py
@bot.command()
async def giveaway(ctx, timer=None):

    if not timer:
        await ctx.send(f"only use #s for seconds. #m for minutes. #h for hours. #d for days. ")
        return

    if '.' not in timer:
        time_in_sec = 0
        if (timer[-1] == 'h') and (timer.count('h') == 1):
            time_in_sec = int(timer[:-1]) * 3600
            type__ = 'hour'
        elif (timer[-1] == 'm') and (timer.count('m') == 1):
            time_in_sec = int(timer[:-1]) * 60
            type__ = 'minute'
        elif (timer[-1] == 's') and (timer.count('s') == 1):
            time_in_sec = int(timer[:-1])
            type__ = 'second'
        elif (timer[-1] == 'd') and (timer.count('d') == 1):
            time_in_sec = int(timer[:-1]) * 86400
            type__ = 'day'
        elif timer.isdigit():
            time_in_sec = int(timer)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"only use #s for seconds. #m for minutes. #h for hours. #d for days. ")
            return

        await ctx.message.delete()

        timestamp = time.time()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"TIMESTAMP TEST",
            timestamp=(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)),
            color=0x40a0c6,
            description=f"**starting giveaway of {timer} {type__}(s)**'")
        embed.set_footer(text='__footer__')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        await asyncio.sleep(time_in_sec)

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"TIMESTAMP TEST",
            timestamp=(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)),
            color=0x40a0c6,
            description=f"**giveaway of {timer} {type__}(s) is over!**")
        embed.set_footer(text='__footer__')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send('**numbers only work**')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for the help [@FluxedScript!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11603043/fluxedscript)

[this also helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924124/adding-hours-to-unix-time-stamp-in-python/13924144)

```
timestamp = time.time() + time_in_sec
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"TIMESTAMP TEST",
        timestamp=(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)),
        color=0x40a0c6,
        description=f"**starting giveaway of {timer} {type__}(s)**'")
    embed.set_footer(text='Giveaway Ends')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [Embed.timestamp](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.timestamp)

```py
import datetime
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"TIMESTAMP TEST",
        timestamp=(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)),
        color=0x40a0c6,
        description=f"**starting giveaway of {timer} {type__}(s)**'")
    embed.set_footer(text='__footer__')
    embed.timestamp = datime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=23,minutes=59)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I get module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now' error if I add the code you send.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question, I managed to get timestamp working after a while, now I am wondering how I would add a certain amount of time to it. Lets say the giveaway ends tomorrow at 21.00, im trying to make the timestamp say tomorrow 21.00 instead of the time it was sent

Comment: @nisico2603 that is adding time onto a datetime string and sorry it was `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Edited my answer